# Plot with labels on the x axis

Tags: r

I want to have a straight line plot of intensity values for 10 different molecules with molecule name on the x axis and intensity value on the y axis.

I tried:

```
x = c("Mol 1","Mol 2","Mol 3","Mol 4","Mol 5","Mol 6","Mol 7","Mol 8","Mol 9","Mol 10")
intensity = c(428,409,388,378,373,140,137,138,139,144)
plot(x,intensity)
```

But it returned this error message?

Error in plot.window(...) : need finite 'xlim' values
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : NAs introduced by coercion
2: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
3: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because your x variable is discrete, you need to do this a little differently:

```
plot(seq_along(x),intensity,type = "l",axes = FALSE)
axis(side = 2)
axis(side = 1,at = seq_along(x),labels = x)
```

The idea being that you create the plot with numerical values for the x axis, and then simply add your particular labels.

You can add a call to `box()` if you miss the full box around the plot.

Comment: That's great! Is there a way to get the plot to display all of the labels (the names are quite long & the font is big so right now only a few are showing).

I would ideally like to rotate them 90 degrees so they're side on and then can all be viewed easily

Comment: @user2846211 Add `las = 2` to the `axis()` call. See `?par` for the documentation on this.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by making your "x" a factor.

```
xFact<-factor(x, levels=x)
plot.default(xFact,intensity)
```

Edited to change `plot` to`plot.default`. As Joran points out, if you just use `plot` you get a boxplot.

Re-edit: To get the x axis to display the proper labels use:

```
plot.default(xFact,intensity,type="p",xaxt="n")
axis(side=1, at=xFact,labels=x)
```

Comment: ...but be aware that this will create a boxplot by default.

Comment: But then you just get 2,4,6,8,10 etc on the x axis instead of "Mol 1", "Mol 2", "Mol 3" etc

Answer (score 1):

Using ggplot:

```
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(id=1:length(x),x,intensity)
ggplot(df)+                               # set default dataset
  geom_point(aes(x=id,y=intensity))+      # plot the points
  scale_x_discrete(labels=x)+             # label the x-axis ticks
  labs(x="Molecule")+                     # label the x axis
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90,vjust=.2,hjust=1))  # rotate and align tick labels
```